# How to remove terminal pin from connector

Tags: electrical

Having some trouble removing terminal pins from a connector. I can see the clip (I think) but can't figure out any way to move it so the pin can slide out.

I have a set of terminal pin removal tools which are essentially just small pieces of metal which I've used without much luck. I've also tried a straightened out hair clip (simply because my tools are tapered at the end, so I wanted to try a flat end)

[Connector photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3yg.jpg)
[Connector photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGM9q.jpg)
[Connector photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAhbC.jpg)

Comment: can you post a pic of your removal tool. There are a multitude of sizes and styles and you need the correct type to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your pictures are too small to show anything useful, but the usual method is (1) push the pin fully *into* the connector, so the back of the locking clip is not wedged against the end of the slot in the connector (2) press down on the locking clip with the removal tool (or something improvised) while you start to pull the pin out.

In step (2) you need to get the back end of the locking clip into the hole in the connector. Press down on the middle of the clip, not right at the back.

Once the pin has started to come out you don't need to keep pressing on the clip. On large connectors like yours, don't expect the pins to just "slide out" easily, you need to pull firmly.

To replace the pin, just push it in until you hear the clip click into the slot and lock it.